# Calculate average difference between a series of DateTime objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`, is there a way to calculate the average of the difference between subsequent elements of the `DateTime` objects using LINQ?

*EDIT*: I realized my original wording was a bit unclear. Just to clarify, I'm looking to average the difference between elements 0 and 1, 1 and 2, 2 and 3, etc.

```cs
double GetAvgDiffInMilliseconds(IEnumerable<DateTime> items)
   => items.Aggregate(/* ??? */).Average();  // is this possible with LINQ?
```

**Note:** I'm not interested in non-LINQ solutions, as this problem is trivially solved with a loop and an accumulator. I'd like to understand if this is possible with LINQ, for learning purposes.

Comment: LINQ operations use iterators and IEnumerable. What you ask is an operator that uses the current and previous item, like [MoreLINQ's Pairwise](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs) operator. Anything else will be a lot more expensive

Comment: To get `Aggregate` to work you'd have to transfer a value, eg a tuple, that contains the previous date, count and sum of differences as the accumulator. `Aggregate`'s body would have to increment the count, calculate the difference between the previous and current value, and emit a new tuple with the incremented count, current value and updated sum of differences. The final step would have to divide the sum by the count. That's *very* ugly and frankly, not worth the trouble

Comment: Do you mean the average distance of all possible combinations from those elemsents, or just N <-> N + 1

Comment: @CSharpie I mean average of the differences between each subsequent entry, so item1 - item0, item2 - item1, etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your help and your answer! I did specify that I am asking for learning purposes only - I understand it's not the best way to go in C# from efficiency perspective, and as I mentioned, I used a loop to solve the issue; however, I know this is possible in other functional languages (and LINQ is modeled after such languages, in my understanding) - hence the question.

Comment: @CoolBots I added how you can use Aggregate to show just how ugly this is. LINQ isn't just the operators bundled in the `System.Linq` namespace. It's the combination of enumerables, enumerators, lambdas and language support. The BCL can't have every possible operator, but new ones *are* added based on demand. I posted a link to the announcement that adds `DistinctBy` to the BCL, something that was available in MoreLINQ in the past

Comment: @CSharpie I clarified my question, for anyone who might find this post useful in the future, based on your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ doesn't have such an operator [yet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/#system-linq-enhancements) but LINQ-to-Objects operations use iterators, enumerators and IEnumerable anyway. What you ask is an operator that uses the current and previous item, like [MoreLINQ's Pairwise](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Pairwise.cs) operator. Such an operation would need only a single iteration to process pairs and produce output. Anything else will be a lot more expensive.

Using `Pairwise` you can write :

```
var avg=items.Pairwise((a, b) => (a - b))
             .Average(ts=>ts.TotalMilliseconds);
```

`Pairwise`'s code is simple and doesn't require multiple iterations :

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Pairwise<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));

        return _(); IEnumerable<TResult> _()
        {
            using var e = source.GetEnumerator();

            if (!e.MoveNext())
                yield break;

            var previous = e.Current;
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return resultSelector(previous, e.Current);
                previous = e.Current;
            }
        }
    }
```

A `Pairwise` method may appear in LINQ at some point. It's a *very* common operation in functional languages, and some `MoreLINQ` operators were added in [.NET Core 6 Preview 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/#system-linq-enhancements), like `DistinctBy`, `MaxBy` and more.

**Using Aggregate**

It's possible to use `Aggregate` to calculate an `Average` but it's *very* ugly and wasteful.

If you had a list of numbers you'd need to carry the item count and sum of items in the accumulator, and calculate the average in the end :

```
    var nums=new[]{1.0,2.0,3.0};
    var avg=nums.Aggregate(
        (cnt:0.0,sum:0.0),
        (acc,c)=>(cnt:acc.cnt+1,sum:acc.sum+c),
        acc=>acc.sum/acc.cnt);
    Console.WriteLine(avg);
```

In this case though you want to calculate the difference between the current item and the previous. This means you need to carry the previous value, the sum of differences, and add the difference between the current and previous value.

You also need to handle the first value, when there's no previous value. And since you calculate differences, the actual count is one less than the collection's count. Finally, if there are only two items you can't divide :

```
    var nums=new[]{DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2)};
    var avg=nums.Aggregate(
        (cnt:0.0,sum:0.0,prev:DateTime.MinValue),
        (acc,c)=>( cnt:acc.cnt+1,
                   sum:(acc.prev==DateTime.MinValue)
                       ?0
                       :acc.sum+(c-acc.prev).TotalMilliseconds,
                   prev:c),
        acc=>acc.cnt==1
             ?acc.sum
             :acc.sum/(acc.cnt-1));
    Console.WriteLine(avg);
```

This prints `60002.95775`. It also took a lot of trial and error and NaN's to get it to work.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer, thank you! `Pairwise` is exactly what I was looking for, but it also is very helpful to understand why `Aggregate` solution turns out quite inefficient. Thank you again for taking the time to write it up!

Comment: @CoolBots if you look at functional languages like F# you'll see they have `fold`, the equivalent of `Aggregate` but also have optimized pairwise methods. Just because something is possible and logically equivalent doesn't mean it's a good idea

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__) if there is more than one element in collection:

```
items.Zip(items.Skip(1))
    .Select(tuple => (tuple.Second - tuple.First).TotalMilliseconds)
    .Average();
```

Comment: This would be great with a source of type `IList<DateTime>`, but enumerating more than once `IEnumerable<T>`s of unknown origin should be avoided at all costs.